# Represent and compare time slots

Tags: java, algorithm

I need to store time slots for restaurant table reservation  and then see if there is any collision...

```
For example - Total tables - 4 
1) 9 - 11 , 3 tables   
2) 9 - 10 , 1 tables (Need to do search if any table left 
                       with constraint to above booking)
```

How do i store the time slots and tables and compare with others...

what data structure should i use...

If i use HashMap what can be the key  and value ,

I have designed all other classes and methods but cant able to find a way to solve time slot collision problem

```
collision example - 

total - 4 tables

1) 9-10 , 3 tables

2) 9-11 , 1 table

3) 9-12 , 2 tables  (collision , table not available)
```

Comment: Can you give an example of a collision?

Comment: I'm not quite sure how you plan to compare tables? Are all 3 tables from 9-11 the same? Or are they unique.  Why not create a custom Reservation type though and create a chained HashMap based on time slots as your key? Then use a linked list at each slot to add the list of available tables?

Comment: @sreisman yes i m not getting any clue how to compare the slots , not tables , every slot will have tables associated , 3 tables are different tables  out of four total tables reserved from 9 a.m to 11 p.m , can u please give example using hashmap chaning to find collisions and how to get list of free tables for any time

Comment: for clear understanding see the problem here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27040264/restaurant-table-reservation

Comment: From looking at that problem description it seems like you would want to use a stack to hold all available tables.  When a table is being used it would be popped off the stack.  If there are no tables in the stack then there are none available.

Comment: @sreisman but how do i manage time slots ...a time slot for particular table

Comment: you would need a stack for each timeslot, otherwise you'd mix them up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simplify the problem, by slicing the available time in blocks of 15 minutes (or whatever other block size is suitable for you). For restaurant reservations I bet that 15 minute blocks are ok.

Then you could have a simple int[] which stores the number of booked tables for each time slot.

Example:
Your restaurant opens from 9 a.m. to 9 p.m., so 12 hours with 4 time slots each. So you need an int[] with 48 slots. Now, when you get a reservation for 3 tables 9 to 11 o'clock, then you increase the first 8 slots (means 9 to 11 o'clock) by 3. The second booking would increase the first 4 slots by 1. If a reservation would increase one of your slots over the available table limit, you know that you need to reject it.

```
final int MAX_TABLES = 4;
final int OPENING= 9;
final int CLOSING= 21;
final int SLOTS= 4;
int[] booking = new int[(CLOSING - OPENING) * SLOTS];

public void main() {
    // no tables booked
    Arrays.fill(booking,0);

    doBooking(3, 0, 8);
    doBooking(1, 4, 8);
    doBooking(1, 4, 12);
}

public void doBooking(int tables, int startSlot, int endSlot) {
    for (int slot= startSlot, slot < endSlot, slot++) {
        if (booking[slot] + tables > MAX_TABLES) {
            throw new Exception("no free table at slot "+slot);
        }
    }
    for (int slot= startSlot, slot < endSlot, slot++) {
        booking[slot] += tables;
    }
}
```

This should give you the idea. There is still stuff to do, e.g. proper exception handling, conversion from time to slots, etc. Note also, that this may be improper java code, as I didn't test it nor did I write it in a GUI.

Comment: you are getting on the idea...please elaborate more with some pseudocode...i m trying this by the way

Comment: if i want a time slot of 1 hour , then let say for 9 a.m -12 p.m , i will have int a[]={0,0,0}={9-10,10-11,11-12} and in every booking i will increment every 0 with the table required for that time slot..9-11 a[]={3,3,0} for 3 tables..am i correct

Comment: Rather than store 0 for each slot I would store the max number of tables available in each slot.  Then for each reservation you can decrement a table or 1 from each value during the slots of the reservation.  Then if you have 0 you know the reservation in that slot is not possible.

Comment: @sreisman yes, that would be possible, too. Depends on semantics and representing booked tables vs. free tables.

Comment: but then after booking...9-11 , after 11 , incrementing also needed right ?

Comment: I don't understand why you would increment after 11 then?

Answer (score 1):

More examples :)
I had the same problem.
I create time slots with interface Slot and using it in the application
As example:

```
Schedule schedule = new Schedule(myduration, unit);
schedule.add(date1, slot1);
schedule.add(date2, slot2);

schedule.get(date1, slot1);
schedule.indexOf(date1, slot1);
schedule.remove(date1, slot1);
schedule.set(date1, index, slot1);
```

More details in github https://github.com/illineya/schedule

Answer (score 0):

For time ranges(make it timestamp or 15 min intervals) use [Guava Range](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/RangesExplained) - it has nice tools to work with ranges (collisions).

Start with open interval from now to future - all tables are available.
New reservation -> check whether there is a free table for the whole interval.
If there is break original interval to three -> before + this + after

Repeat...

Comment: cant use third party api

Answer (score 0):

You can create a TimeSlot objects and compare each start and endtimes.

```
public class TimeSlot {

    private int startTime;
    private int endTime;


    public TimeSlot(int start, int end){
     this.startTime = start;
     this.endTime = end;


    }



}
```

Comment: already done this..created a set of timeslot overridden compare to method , and compare method